# Visual Studio Codeで拡張機能をインストールできない

Tags: python, vscode

Visual Studio Codeを使い始めようとしています。
利用目的は、pythonのコーディングです。
利用開始にあたりpython拡張機能と日本語パックを導入しようとしていますが、
一行にインストール始まりません。
別のPCでは特に問題なくインストールできているのですが。。。

この事象の原因もしくは切り分けのための情報などあれば、ご提供いただけないでしょうか。

なお、他の拡張機能も同様に「インストールしています」でとまってしまいます。
また、ローカルファイルとしてダウンロードしてからのインストールも試してみましたが
状況は改善していません。

よろしくお願いします。

環境情報

- OS:Windows 10(home edition)
- VS Code: 1.23.1

Comment: インストールできた PC　と失敗した PCの違いからですね。 Windowsのバージョンとか。セキュリティソフトの問題も良く言われますが、それらはどうなのでしようか?

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
セキュリティソフトは同じものの同じバージョン
OSもwindows10の同一ビルド番号です。
ただ、はまっているパソコンのOSはwindows 10のhome
うまくいっているやつはprofessionalです。

Comment: home と Proの違い、調べても意味のある差はなさそうですね。
自分も WIn10 Proで使っていますが、特に問題無し。(この関連では) 申し訳ないですが、役に立てそうもありません。　あとは、WIndowsのログに何かエラーが出ていないかくらいしか思いつかない。

Comment: ありがとうございます。イベントログなどはみているのですが、どうにもわからず。VS Codeのログを参照してみます。なにかわかれば、また記載します。お忙しい中回答くださりありがとうございます。＜逆に、VS Codeにこだわる必要はないので、Pycharmなりで代用します。

Comment: VS Code のバージョンも本文に記載頂けませんか？　基本的に VS Code + Windows 10 Home の拡張機能まわりで目立ったバグは無いはずで、となると何か最近発生したバグなのかもしれません。

Comment: 本日、該当のPCを再セットアップ。その後インストールしたら問題なく拡張機能を導入することができました。Visual Studio環境を複数いれていたのが悪かったのか、Windows updateの際に問題が生じたのか定かではなく、もうしわけありませが、いったん本件の決着をみたので、ご連絡します。